# Trigger gitlab pipeline based on file type or extension

Tags: gitlab-ci

I trying to build a conditional pipeline that is only triggered with a certain file type or extension is being pushed.

For example, when pushing my markdown files I would like to compile and generate html, txt,...

Looking at the documentation, I see that there is support for [only or except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified) but they are relying only of tags, commit messages,... but it's not possible to specify the files modified in the commit. An extension of the only/except will look like:

```
only:
    files:
        - *.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not built-in. You may write your own implementation but do note that if you want to compare with previous commit and you push several commits at once the build may be skipped as by default the jobs are only run for the latest commit. It would be a lot easier to just build the static site always.

A simplest way to implement it would be just to grep the result of git diff and end the job if the files don't match.

```
 before_script:
   - if  ! grep "\.md$" <(git diff --name-only HEAD~1); then exit; fi;
```

Comment: Great! Just wanted to add the fact that the `before_script` should be added to all steps in case the are artifacts dependencies between steps.